# Apache doesn't have access to web root directory

Tags: php, macos, apache, .htaccess, web

First of all I want to apologise for my bad english.
So, I have Apache 2.4.23 on MacOS Sierra. Everything worked fine, but at some point it stopped working good. When I try to open some file or directory on my web server it throw an error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
```

Though it must show content of the page. It happens with all of my files and directories. I've alredy added them to the group _www, in wich Apache runs, and make chmod -R 775 but it doesn't helps. Also doesn't helps chmod -R 777. May be I run Apache with another user or group? I think, no, because in config setted up _www as user and group also. That's what "ps aux | grep httpd" says:

```
_www              9877   0,0  0,0  2480792   2040   ??  S     6:43     0:00.01 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
_www              9864   0,0  0,0  2480792   1612   ??  S     6:43     0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
_www              9863   0,0  0,0  2480792   2020   ??  S     6:43     0:00.01 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
_www              9862   0,0  0,0  2480792   1628   ??  S     6:43     0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
_www               222   0,0  0,0  2480792   1744   ??  S    сб08    0:00.02 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
root                90   0,0  0,1  2481048   7808   ??  Ss   сб08    0:01.40 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
alankabisov      10122   0,0  0,0  2423384    240 s000  R+    6:58     0:00.00 grep httpd
```

As we can see it runs under _www. At this moment I have two questions:
1) Why there are some different instances of httpd?
2) Why one is under root? As I thnik, becuse I run it through "sudo apachectl start"

That's my Apache vhosts config:

```
<Directory "/Users/alankabisov/Sites">
  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/alankabisov/Sites/%1/"
  ServerName sites.dev
  ServerAlias *.dev
  UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>
```

So I can access my sites through *.dev domains. For example abc.dev points to abc folder from web root.

Also I have some strange error in my Apache error log:

```
[Mon Mar 13 18:45:27.113487 2017] [core:crit] [pid 9877] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:58513] AH00529: /Users/alankabisov/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/Users/alankabisov/' is executable, referer: http://php1.dev/

[Mon Mar 13 18:45:27.297229 2017] [core:crit] [pid 9877] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:58513] AH00529: /Users/alankabisov/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/Users/alankabisov/' is executable

[Mon Mar 13 18:45:27.359012 2017] [core:crit] [pid 9877] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:58513] AH00529: /Users/alankabisov/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/Users/alankabisov/' is executable, referer: http://php1.dev/
```

I find strange that Apache complains for problems of reading htaccess file that locates in the /Users/alankabisov/ directory, but not in the /Users/alankabisov/Sites as set on my vhosts conf.

Hope you will help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems that I've solved the problem. Apache looked for htaccess file in the parent directories of the web root and didn't have access to read in that directory. So I've added this directory to group _www and gave for it read permissions. It helped me. May be the solution is not the best, but it helps.

Comment: hello, would you share step by step what did you do?